Product of sub-Gaussian and Bernoulli random variable
Any input on the following problem is appreciated. I have a mean-zero sub-Gaussian random variable $X_1\sim\mathsf{sG}(\sigma)$ and a Bernoulli random variable $X_2\sim\mathsf{Be}(p)$ which are not necessarily independent. I am interested in learning if $X_1\cdot X_2$ is also sub-Gaussian.
I can show that if $X_\ell\sim\mathsf{sG}(\sigma^2_\ell), \ell=1,2$ (not necessarily independent), then $X_1\cdot X_2$ is sub-Exponential with parameters $(4\sigma_1\sigma_2, 4\sqrt{2}\sigma_1\sigma_2)$. Thus, by using the fact a Bernoulli is a sub-Gaussian random variable with parameter $1/2$, I can use the above result and conclude that in my case $X_1\cdot X_2\sim\mathsf{sE}(2\sigma, 2\sqrt{2}\sigma)$. However, I feel I'm leaving a lot on the plate by just using the fact that $X_2$ is bounded and not taking advantage of the fact that $X_2$ is Bernoulli.
Thank you for your time!

One way to see this is the following equivalence:
$$
(1) \qquad \qquad X_1 \sim \mathsf{subG}(\sigma) \Leftrightarrow
\mathbb{E}\exp\left(\frac{X_1^2}{K^2}\right) \leq 2, \quad
\text{for some $K > 0$}.
$$
In particular, $K = C \sigma$ for some $C > 0$ (see Proposition 2.5.2 in High-dimensional probability).
Using this and the fact that $X_2^2$ is always bounded by $1$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
\exp\left(\frac{(X_1 X_2)^2}{K^2}\right)
\right] =
\mathbb{E}\left[
\exp\left(\frac{X_1^2 X_2^2}{K^2}\right)
\right] \leq
\mathbb{E}\left[
\exp\left(\frac{X_1^2}{K^2}\right)
\right] \leq 2,
$$
using the same $K$ that appears in ($1$). Therefore, $X_1 \cdot X_2$ is also subgaussian.

Awesome! It also squares up with the intuition that $X_2$ is "just truncating" some parts of the distribution of $X_1$ depending on their correlation, as such it shouldn't really affect the tail behavior. Thanks a lot!
